# Exploiting symmetry of variables in minimizing problem.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Find the points on $x^2=yz+5$ that are closest to the origin.

One obvious way is to minimize the distance squared from the origin, using partial derivatives and the hessian.

However, my teacher also told us that $y$ and $z$ are symmetrical, so instead minimizing $z^2+x^2+y^2$ we can minimize $2y^2+x^2$. And when $2y^2+x^2$ is on our surface, exploiting symmetry again we can replace $z$ by $y$:

So we minimize $2y^2+y(y)+5=3y^2+5$

I'm confused as why we can replace $z$ by $y$ just because $z$ is symmetrical to $y$. Can someone please explain.

Comment: You are minimizing on the plane of symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

consider the function $$F(x,y,z,\lambda)=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}+\lambda(x^2-yz-5)$$